# Git Flow - Não está criando a tag na master

Tags: git, git-flow

Começamos a trabalhar a pouco tempo com GitFlow e estamos com um problema que não está criando a tag na master...

Quando vamos gerar uma versão em produção (master),

Criamos uma branch de release: `git flow release start <versao>`

Publicamos ela para todos terem acesso: `git flow release publish <versao>`

E finalizamos ela: `git flow release finish <versao>`

Porem quando damos o `finish`, acontece desta forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pelo que entendo, a tag foi criada na `develop` e quando vou ao `Azure DevOps` em tags, não foi criada a tag la... 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> **O que estamos fazendo de errado? Ou o que falta fazermos?**

Comment: Só para esclarecimento, ao finalizar a branch release, é realizado um merge tanto em develop quanto na master. Ou seja, a tag é criada sem nenhum atrelamento as branchs. A única coisa que ocorre é na hora de criar, que é baseada na develop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para enviar uma tag, você precisa fazer o push dela. É só usar o `git push` com a instrução `--tags`:

```
git push origin --tags
```

Ou então:

```
git push origin nome-tag
```

Comment: com o `git push --tags` funcionou